# × Package install failed, see above. The Schematic workflow failed. See above

Tags: node.js, angular

When I run **ng new project-1** in command prompt, it shows this error.

**× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.**

I tried installing node latest version, but again I got this error.

Hope you can help me with this.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: And "above" is... what?

Answer (score 0):

I installed angular/cli latest version through follo, and it solved the problem.

**npm i @angular/cli**